# Can we use JitterBit Loader it import data into 2 related objects in a single load?

Tags: articles, jitterbit

Can we use JitterBit Loader it import data into 2 related objects in a single load ?

Right now we are loading it twice using dataloader

1. Import parent object
2. Export Parent Object and update csv
3. Import Child Object

Can we do this in single import uisng JitterBit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that Jitterbit just extends dataloader functionality. You have to describe how child is related to parent. That's why you are using three operations.

But you can reduce it to two operations by implementing external Id in you parent object. Just define in csv external Id for parent and provide it for correspondent children records.

[How do I use an External ID to import related records?](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000002783)

You will get rid of pulling and populating Ids.

Another way is to utilize [SObject Tree](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm)

But it will require some programming. I'd prefer to create win service, which runs python. And in python you can do implement your extract, import etc.

Comment: I am trying to import articles and their data categories. One article can have one or more data categories. Even after exporting I have to duplicate the rows if article has more than one data category ? Any alternative solution ?

Comment: Data categories is not child record of article, its metadata. You should consider it as field, not relationship. I can only recommend you to use excel do build your csv. Excel has vlookup functionality.

Comment: Article Title, Description, Attachment .. etc are on article type object and ArticleId, DataCategoryGroup and DataCategoryName are on DataCategory.ArticleType object when I use the data Loader. We can do this in Article import but only 10MB at a time